# Node Class with Value of Arbitrary Type, Fortran 2003

Tags: oop, generics, fortran

I have not found the host of information on generics in Fortran to be useful.

I would like to create a Node class that:

1. Contains a variable of arbitrary class, "ANYTHING :: value,"
2. the class of which can be specified either (a) at instantiation or (b) through an init subroutine.

Ideally, I would like to imitate the Java functionality of:

```
Node<Integer> n = new Node<Integer>();
```

Is this possible in Fortran 2003? Or will I have to create a Node-derived class for every possible class that 'value' might have?

The solution presented in the first post does not quite accomplish what I want. Consider:

```
program generics_test

implicit none

type node_int
    integer :: x
end type node_int

type node
  class(*), allocatable :: value
end type node

type(node) :: obj

allocate(node_int :: obj%value)

!This must be used:
select type (val => obj%value)
  type is (node_int)
    val%x = 1
  class default
    !throw en error
end select


end program generics_test
```

This illustrates the main issue: the need for `select type` to interact with an allocated unlimited polymorphic object. Take for example:

```
module node_class

  type node
    class(*), allocatable :: anything

    contains
      procedure, public :: init => init_sub
  end type node

  private :: init_sub

  contains

    subroutine init_sub(this, something)
      class(node)         :: this
      somethingObj        :: something ! <--- this assumes we know what soemthing is;
                                       ! generous, since my question doesn't assume that
      allocate(this%anything, source=something)
    end subroutine init_sub

end module node_class
```

It seems that, although you may take `class(*), allocatable :: anything` and `allocate(anythingObj, source=somethingObj)` somewhere inside of `type node`, `node` cannot **ever** treat `anything` as though it were a `somethingObj` unless `anything` appears in a `select type... type is (somethingObj)` block. Thus, to emulate the snippet of Java I've written above `select type` would have to have a case for every single object that will **ever** be encountered.

Comment: You have to use the `select type` blocks when dealing with the allocated type of unlimited polymorphic.

Comment: Can you edit the above program to demonstrate this? More importantly, doesn't this require you to know the type for which you are checking?

Comment: Yes, of course it requires it, but if you assign 1 to something, you have to know what type it is!

Comment: It defeats the purpose to require the definition of my Node-object to know what types it may contain. To imitate the Java snippet, the Node-object should be able to contain any class without revision of its definition. Thus, if "select type... end select" is required, it's not truly generic and the answer is just "No."

Comment: @user20672 I'm not able to comment on Java-like, but the definition of `node` doesn't "need to know" allowed component types: it's whatever is _using_ a `node`.  If there's a subroutine which is going to compare the value of two nodes then yes, it really is going to have to know how to do that comparison.

Comment: @francescalus I understand your point. If the node just contains something, then in the context of the procedure it's known what it contains and operations in the procedure may act on it accordingly. My question is less complicated than that. I want a generic object, Alpha, in the Node-object. My question is whether, **in my main program**, I can specify the class of Alpha [to be an arbitrary class] in a fashion similar to the Java snippet.  So far, the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have a component an *unlimited polymorphic entity*.

```
type node_int
end type node_int

type node
  class(*), allocatable :: value
end type node

type(node) obj

allocate(node_int :: obj%value)

end
```

Here, the `class(*)` is your "ANYTHING" (even, thanks to @IanH correcting me, intrinsic types) and the `allocate` statement sets the type.

It is possible, if you want to get closer to Java-ness to override the structure constructor, so that

```
obj = node(mold)
```

works, where the dynamic type is taken from `mold`.  [Fortran 2008 has the `mold=` specifier in `allocate`.]  But I won't go into that unless requested.

Depending on exactly what you want to do you may find this approach is much more work than having distinct types.

**Edit, following question update**

When one then wants to use the value of an unlimited polymorphic entity as given above, one is tempted by something like

```
allocate (integer :: obj%value)
obj%value = 1
```

This won't work without the Fortran 2008 rules of automatic allocation.  [In the question one has an `x` component of node_int, but I'll just pretend `node_int` is itself an `integer`.]

Instead, one can use sourced allocation:

```
allocate (obj%value, source=1)
```

or a `select type` construct

```
select type ( x => obj%value)
 type is(integer)
  x = 1
end select
```

[This is the heart of my suggestion that it's a lot of work.]

**A more detailed example, including sourced allocation and constructor**

```
module types

  type Penguin
     character(len=20) :: name
  end type Penguin

  type node
    class(*), allocatable :: value
  end type node

  interface node
     module procedure node_c
  end interface node

 contains

   function node_c(value)
     class(*), intent(in) :: value
     type(node) node_c

     allocate(node_c%value, source=value)
   end function node_c

end module types

program test

  use types
  type(node) obj(3)

  allocate(obj(1)%value, source = 1)
  allocate(obj(2)%value, source = Penguin('Percy'))
  obj(3) = node(Penguin('Harold'))

  do i=1, 3
     select type (val => obj(i)%value)
     type is (integer)
        print '("Value is an integer: ", I0)', val
     class is (Penguin)
        print '("Value is a penguin called ", A)', TRIM(val%name)
     end select
  end do

end
```

Output from the above, compiled with ifort 14.0.1

> Value is an integer: 1
>   Value is a penguin called Percy
>   Value is a penguin called Harold

Comment: What do you mean "class(*) doesn't cover intrinsic types such as integer"?

Comment: @francescalus could you please explain how to override the structure constructor?

Comment: Just use a interface block named `node` with a function returning the structure.

Comment: This does not accomplish what I want. I've edited the question to demonstrate that.

Comment: I don't think that you can use, "allocate(x, source=y)"   **OR**   "select type ... end select". I think Vladimir is saying **you must always use "select type... end select,"** regardless of how you allocate. Is that right, Vladimir? If that's true, the correct answer to my question is, "No. You cannot [really] imitate the above-shown Java functionality in Fortran." Why? Because your Node-object must have the classes it may contain hard-coded into its definition. That's not required in the Java snippet I included.

Comment: It depends whether you need parametric polymorphism, where the class can have specialization for every type, or something like a container for `void*`. `class(*)` is more like the latter, you must use type-guards to retrieve the values. But you can also simulate templates in Fortran. Preprocessors are used for this.

Comment: @user20672 Sourced allocation, and the F2008 assignment, don't need the classes hard-coding in the same way that a `select type` construct would.  At some point, though, to do something useful with the values the polymorphism is going to have to be reduced.  And @VladimirF mentions one approach.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks Vladimir. I need, and thought that the Java snippet indicated, the first of Vladimir's two choices. I would not consider using a prepocessor an acceptable solution, and the answer would remain "No. You cannot do this in Fortran." If it's possible, I would be nearly as content if a parent class could contain an abstract variable, and it's derived classes could specify the type of that variable. Vladimir, do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @francescalus using sourced allocation without the 'select type' block resulted in compilation error for me with the **Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 14.0.1.139** compiler. It seems to me that you need the 'select type' block regardless. Could you provide a small program that compiles and runs for you to demonstrate otherwise?

Comment: @user20672 Using my first program block, replacing the allocation line with `allocate(obj%value, source = 1)` compiles fine with ifort 14.0.1.106, and produces the correct result: `obj%value` is an `integer` with value `1`.  [To print the result I do need a `select type` construct.]

Comment: @francescalus Thanks. Mine wasn't compiling because I was using a direct assignment after I allocated, but not in a 'select type' block. You wrote earlier that "allocate (integer :: obj%value)
obj%value = 1" was okay, which is not true. I then corrected this with your source suggestion but intentionally broke it to make a point to myself by doing something like "allocate(couldBeAnything, source=node1) couldBeAnything%myInteger = 1," which doesn't compile. This is because, like you and Vladimir mentioned earlier, to imbue couldBeAnything with the properties of Node, you must use 'select type.'

Comment: Because you must use 'select type,' I'm convinced definitively that the answer is "No. You cannot replicate the functionality of that snippet of Java in Fortran." Suppose we have class(*), allocatable :: a. We allocate it somewhere, allocate(a, source=anythingObj). Now any procedure that accepts 'a' as an argument cannot treat it as an anythingObj unless I specifically include a 'select type... type is anythingObj' block in the procedure. This is an issue for, say, an overloaded operator, which I might use in generic data structures for generic comparisons.

Comment: The issue is that I have to anticipate every possible object I will ever create or constantly rewrite the code. It would be more preferable if all I assumed was that the operator is defined for whatever generic argument I get ===> I don't need to know what the object is. If you would like to summarize this conclusion in addition to the points you've made (which do a nice job of showing what the limited generics Fortran CAN do), I'll accept the answer. Be sure to make clear where a 'select type' block is needed and the limitations of class(*) that I've pointed out.

Comment: @user20672 `obj%value=1` is fine (and the `allocate` redundant) but only under the rules of intrinsic assignment/automatic allocation of F2008 - which are possibly not supported by ifort 14.0.1.  I really can't speak about replicating Java features, so I recommend that you gather your comments and place them in a new answer, although they do seem to be beyond the obvious scope of the question.

Comment: I will address all of these issues in an answer. Thanks for your help.